# Separate module for client usage

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven application. One of the modules is the EJB module and the other is a shared module with entities, utility classes etc. So when my client wants to use my application he/she needs to declare 2 dependencies - `ejb-client.jar` and `shared-module.jar`.

My question is: Is it worth introducing new `client` modules, which will simply collect two dependencies - `ejb-client` and `shared`? So client will declare only one dependency - `client` module, instead of two.

Comment: Why does the client have to declare both dependencies? Doesn't ejb-client use the shared-module and hence the client would get that dependency transitively?

Comment: If a client needs the classes in `shared` perhaps they should go in the `ejb-client` JAR or referenced transitively from same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the module that builds ejb-client.jar has a dependency on the module that builds the share-module.jar?

Assuming that's the case, any client need only depend on the ejb-client.jar module and the dendency on the share-module.jar module will be picked up transitively.

Answer (score 1):

If your clients need direct dependencies to several artifacts, it's a best practice to introduce a POM module which captures these dependencies:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html

Of course, you only need this if clients need the dependencies directly (not transitivly).